# Getting selected Text Value from NSComboBox

Tags: arrays, macos, cocoa, xcode-storyboard, nscombobox

I'm trying to get the selected string from comboBox.The string casting is not working

```
   let font = NSFont(name:String(combo_font.objectValueOfSelectedItem), size: 50)
```

How to properly get the string value?

Comment: `NSComboBox` is a subclass of `NSTextField`, try `stringValue`

Comment: @vadian Thanks .. it worked.Do you want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSComboBox` is a subclass of `NSTextField`, it's simply

```
NSFont(name: combo_font.stringValue, size: 50)
```

Comment: Can you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61301345/nscombobox-selection-changed-event-not-firing